# My answers are 5, 4, 3, 2,but when I run the code ,the answers are 5, 4.Why?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
num = 5
if num > 2:
    print(num)
    num -= 1
print(num）
```

Here are my thoughts:5>2,5,4; 4>2,4,3; 3>2,3,2; 2.So my answers are the 5, 4, 3, 2 but when I run the code,the answers are the 5 ,4. I really don't understand it.

Comment: What do you think 'if' does?

Comment: because you need to use a `while`, not an `if`.

Comment: What did you try to look into before posting this question? `if` statements only happen once. It is not called an "if-loop"

Comment: How can you loop with an `if`? You need to check your code more carefully before asking..

Answer (score 3):

use `while` instead of `if`.

```
>>> num = 5
>>> while num > 2:
...     print(num)
...     num -= 1
# 5
# 4
# 3
>>> print(num)
# 2
```